# What are the top things to do in Istanbul, Turkey?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines, nightlife

I'm planing my holiday trip to turkey. give me suggestions what it likes.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what do you expect from it. I lived in Istanbul for 2 months and have few historical or famous places that i can recommend.

- Eminonu, it's like a wonderland you can find everything, and it's usually cheap.
- Hagia sophia
- Basilika cistern
- Blue mosque, these 3 things are in the same district, pretty cool.
- Dolmabahce Palace
- Turkish baths
- Grand bazaar
- Maiden tower
- Islands

Well it's really a big city there are more things to discover. Cheers